# @vue-cli peer dependency warn

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

I created project using vue-cli 3, cd into it, ran npm install and got this error:

```
npm WARN ajv-keywords@2.1.1 requires a peer of ajv@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

I ran

```
npm install ajv
```

Which finished with success, but I'm still getting same warn on npm install

Comment: Delete the package-lock.json file and try to run `npm install` again

Comment: Nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install -g npm-install-peers
```

try this it will add all the missing peers and remove all the error

Comment: You've included the global tag `-g` in your answer. It would be helpful to point out why you've done that as the question did not specify a global install.